# Capturing when an activity is started from FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP intent flag

Tags: android, android-intent, android-toast

I have a root activity (call root), and user when clicking on one of the views in root will be taken to a child.

Sometimes, (usually based on a condition), user will be taken directly from child to root using the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

How do I find out, in root (Mainactivity), if root has been started from child.

Usecase: I want to show a `Toast` when user is shown the MainActivity, only when he comes from child with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag.

So I want to be able to do the following:

In `MainActivity` or `root`:

```
  if (came_from_child_with_intent_flag()){
       showToast()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add extras to your intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("isFromChild", true); //Your id
intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your onCreate of Root get the extra like this:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
Boolean value = b.getBoolean("isFromChild");
```

if its not from child then vaule will be equals to null
and if dosent have extras then bundle will be null to.